# Apple Wallet / Passbook / Passkit: Register for push endpoint is called over and over

Tags: passbook, passkit, apple-wallet

We have implemented the **register for push** endpoint, but sometimes the endpoint is called with exactly the same arguments over and over up to a couple of thousand times.
The first call returns 201 and the rest returns 200 just like the [documentation][1] specifies.

Is there anything other than the http status code that could cause it to retry like this?
[1]: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/walletpasses/register_a_pass_for_update_notifications

Comment: Can you reproduce this on one of your own devices? You can enable logging for Passkit and check to see if there is something about the response the device doesn't like. Could there be caching that is returning the 201? Are you sending updates to the pass inadvertently?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to reproduce this.
I've checked the Passkit logs and found that we have implemented the unauthorized response incorrectly, we return 403 instead of 401, I will fix that, but could that really cause this kind of behaviour?
The number of unauthorized requests aren't even close to the number of 200 responses.
No, there's no caching in place.

Comment: > Are you sending updates to the pass inadvertently?
You mean from the server or from the device?
I'm pretty new on this Passkit stuff..